# Notifying ViewController from custom UIImageView subclass

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview, subclass

I want to define a class of draggable images subclassing UIImageView, separating how they look (on the subclass) and what the user interface react to where they move (on the viewcontroller)

myType1Image.h

```
@interface myType1Image : UIImageView { }
```

myType1Image.m

```
...
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
// Retrieve the initial touch point 
} 
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
// Move relative to the original touch point with some special effect
} 
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
// Notify the ViewController ... here is my problem...how?
// would call GotIt on viewController for example
}
...
```

viewcontroller implementation

```
....
  myType1Image *img = [[myType1Image alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iOSDevTips.png"]];
  img.center = CGPointMake(110, 75);
  img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [subview addSubview:img];
...

- (void) gotIt:(id) (myType1Image *)sender{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint( myimage.frame, [sender.center] )){
        NSLog(@"Got IT!!!");
    }
}

....
```

I can't figure out how ViewController could be notified from the myType1Image class, for touchesEnded (for example). 
I did it writing all code on the viewcontroller, but I want to do it using subclasses so I can separate the event handling and the visualization of the images from the real funcionality of my interface.
So if I have 15 draggable images, I haven't to guess what image is touching, and deciding the visual effects to apply.

Is it possible? Is an erroneus aproach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, class names should always begin with a capital letter (`MyType1Image`).

Create a `MyType1ImageDelegate` protocol in which you declare delegate methods that the image view sends to its delegate (the view controller). The first argument of these methods should always be of the type `MyType1Image *` (to tell the delegate from which object the message comes).

Your `MyType1Image` also needs a `id <MyType1ImageDelegate> delegate` property.

When your view controller creates an image view, it sets itself as the image view's delegate. Whenever the image view wants to send a message to the view controller, you have it send the message to the delegate.

Comment: Thanks. Delegates are something now for me. 
I suppose that lets more than one message type in the protocol..for what I investigated  
@protocol MyType1ImageControllerDelegate
- (void)MyType1ImageViewControllerMoved:(MyType1ImageViewController*)myType1ImageViewController;
- (void)MyType1ImageViewControllerEnded:(MyType1ImageViewController*)myType1ImageViewController;
@end

Comment: Sure, the protocol can contain as many methods as you want it to. Just remember the naming conventions: names of classes and protocols begin with a capital letter, method names begin with a lowercase letter.